# ActionController::ActionControllerError in CommentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following is the controller

```
    class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body, :post_id)
    end

    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment_params])
        if @comment.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Comment was succesfully posted.'
            redirect_to(@comment.post)
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Error creating comments: #{@comment.errors}"
            redirect_to(@comment.post)
        end
    end
end
```

All I see is,

```
ActionController::ActionControllerError in CommentsController#create
Cannot redirect to nil!

Rails.root: c:/sites/myrubyblog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

By commenting the redirect_to in else block will through a different error saying missing template!

did try the few solutions from previously asked questions, but nothing is helping!

Comment: could you post your form as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not `params[:comment_params]` but `comment_params`, you should change your `create` action to this and  ensure your `post_id` is set:

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body, :post_id)
    end

    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Comment was succesfully posted.'
            redirect_to(@comment.post)
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Error creating comments: #{@comment.errors}"
            redirect_to(@comment.post)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your else block are also redirecting to @comment.post even though it's not saved. So basically it is nil.
 I don't think your comment is being saved. Try doing this to find out if there is any error

```
if @comment.save! # this will show errors if any
  ...
else
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  redirect_to post
end
```

I am assuming your params has post_id in it. If not @comment.post will also be nil. Causing that error in both if and else blocks.

Comment: by commenting redirect_to in else block will through an error: `Missing template comments/create, inherited_resources/base/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "c:/sites/myrubyblog/app/views" * "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.1.1/app/views" * "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f0243d495067/app/views" * "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.17.0/app/views"`

Answer (score 0):

```
else
   flash[:notice] = "Error creating comments: #{@comment.errors}"
   redirect_to(@comment.post) <--
end
```

When it failed to save, it tries to redirect to `@comment.post`, but it's nil because you didn't set `post_id` correctly

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment_params])
```

Which should be

```
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
```